# Is there anything opposite to category of cocoa?

Tags: cocoa, objective-c-category

Is there anyway that I can remove a method that is added in category?
I dont want to subclass or comment that category?
Kindly tell me what will happen if I create a category use it and later on I want not to use it anymore. 
I am new to cocoa, so any help and suggestions please....

Comment: The short answer is sort of, the long answer is very long and something you probably don't want to do. If you explain your use case in more detail someone might be able to offer suggestions for your situation.

Comment: Actually I was asked, is there any technique/way to remove/hide a method from a class without subclassing it, as you add a method in a class without subclassing (category).

Comment: Do you want to override method?

Comment: @ParagBafna : No I dont want to override, instead I want to hide that method without subclassing it!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective-C is a dynamic language and lacks any strong concept of hiding; public, private, protected etc.; methods, especially at runtime. As a consequence of this a child class cannot hide an inherited method, which is possible in some languages.

So the simple, and recommended answer, is that you cannot remove or hide a method.

But given the very dynamic nature of Objective-C, never say never... but really you shouldn't go there!

The standard way to reduce the exposure of a class is to have another class privately own an instance of the class and moderate all access to it. If you are pattern-oriented you will find patterns which do this.